# SQLNCLI11 for linked server "my linked server" returned message "Query timeout expired."

Tags: sql-server, timeout

We have two separate sql servers. On one server we have a datawarehouse DWH, on the other we have sales information.

Now on the DWH server there is an ETL job that collects the information from the sales server. The job runs daily after midnight. The DWH collects the information via linked server from the sales database.

Now, the most time the ETL job runs without any problems. But sometimes it failes because of query timeout. We have found out, that there is a specific pattern: The failure happens every 11th day. So on the 11th day the ETL job fails to collect information.

We have searched everthing and could not found out what this issue causes. Also we know that the amout of data is everytime, almost the same.

Does anyone have a clue or any idea, where i can search for such a problem?